# Export WIT xml failed

Tags: azure-devops

I was trying to export a WIT XML from Visual Studio 2019 - Professional

[image: export from visual studio]

but I got the message as the attached snapshot

[image: error]

Error exporting work item type definition: The feature is disabled....
I was told that I need to be the project administrator. Yes, I've the admin permission for this project, but still didn't work for me.

Anything else that I need to config? Thanks.

I have followed the above instructions, but I then get the following error:-

From a previous post:-
"@Totoro There are two models for work item customization. The one you're trying to use from Visual Studio is the **old** one, and it does not work against VSTS (except in the case where the account was migrated from an on-prem TFS instance). –
Daniel Mann
Aug 17, 2018 at 13:28"

Please advise how I resolve this with the NEW model for WIT customisation

From a previous post:-
"@Totoro There are two models for work item customization. The one you're trying to use from Visual Studio is the **old** one, and it does not work against VSTS (except in the case where the account was migrated from an on-prem TFS instance). –
Daniel Mann
Aug 17, 2018 at 13:28"

Please advise how I resolve this with the NEW model for WIT customisation

Answer (score 0):

Visual studio does not support the NEW model ([About process customization and inherited processes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/work/inheritance-process-model?view=azure-devops&tabs=agile-process)). To create, edit, and manage processes, you must be a member of the **Project Collection Administrators** group. Then use the organization settings to manage your processes: [Create and manage inherited processes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/work/manage-process?view=azure-devops)